# Android MedicCodec: How to record a video file from camera and stream the video to the web?

Tags: android, video-streaming, video-capture, android-mediacodec

I want to build an Android application, that record a video from camera, and at the same time, stream the video to the web.

I want to build the app based on the example of CameraCaptureActivity.java in grafika-master. But I have no idea where to plug in the streaming function.

Comment: What are you planning to use to do the video streaming?

Comment: Right now have no clear plan. For example, display on a web homepage? Actually I think it does not matter much I guess. If I can display the video stream, I can do some video processing too.

Answer (score 0):

I would say try looking at VideoEncoderCore.drainEncoder() , especially where bytes are downstreamed to muxer - mMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mBufferInfo); 
For connection oriented streaming rtp/hls/mpeg-dash, etc  you have to complete handshake phase in outer code, and just push packets here. 
Also some streaming examples available in libstreaming : https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples

Comment: libsreaming-example used the MediaRecorder and set the output as the socket, rather than the output file. This means the streaming has taken the place of the recording. So this example is not applicable. I guess we need to put the framedata to the streaming socket.